# User current Location on a mapkit in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit

I need a good tutorial in which user's current location (latitude,longitude,city,state,country) is found and updated from time to time as the location changes and displayed on the map kit with the blue icon zooming.

I did it by placing an MKMapView on view.xib and it shows current location of user (default on simulator :SanFransisco) with blue dot zooming only for the first time. But when I run the app next time it is not showing any blue dot zooming. Should I write any code? Till now I didn't write any code. Just placed a mapkit with Show UserLocation checked in xib. How can I get a blue dot ?

I also need to find nearby doctors from the userlocation and display in the same map with red coloured markers pointing.

Gone through google but confused a lot. Please suggest to me some good tutorials in this regard.

EDIT:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [self queryGooglePlaces:@"doctor"];
}

-(void) queryGooglePlaces: (NSString *) googleType {

    // https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#Authentication
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=300&types=doctor&sensor=true&key=%@",  coord.latitude, coord.longitude,kGOOGLE_API_KEY];


    NSURL *googleRequestURL=[NSURL URLWithString:url];

        dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: googleRequestURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}
```

//Here I'm getting array data as null because latitude and longitude are passed as 0.000 ..

How can I get both of them on viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find the near doctor address you need to use "GOOGLE PLACE API"

//For user current location

CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [[[mapview userLocation] location] coordinate];
NSLog(@"Location found from Map: %f %f",location.latitude,location.longitude);

[Check this link its good example of google place api](http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.in/2011/07/working-with-google-places-api.html)

Comment: you get only latitude and longitude of current city if you want to use the state name and city and country name then you want to use the google place api

Comment: I can c them.But I couldn't see both users location and nearby doctors on viewDidLoad bcoz after [locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; it is simply going to [self queryGooglePlaces:@"doctor"]; without calling - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation event

Answer (score 0):

Add this Delegate method of ccl location manager

.h file

```
double currentLatitude;
double currentLongitude;

  - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
               fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
    {

        currentLatitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;

        currentLongitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;

        [self  queryGooglePlaces:somestring];
    }

-(void) queryGooglePlaces: (NSString *) googleType {

    // https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#Authentication
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=300&types=doctor&sensor=true&key=%@",  currentLatitude , currentLongitude,kGOOGLE_API_KEY];


    NSURL *googleRequestURL=[NSURL URLWithString:url];

        dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: googleRequestURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}
```

pass the current latitude and longitude in your `-(void) queryGooglePlaces: (NSString *) googleType { }` method

Comment: I have already added them .Problem is both are not showing on viewDidLoad bcoz after [locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; it is simply going to [self queryGooglePlaces:@"doctor"]; without calling - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation event

Comment: call your -(void) queryGooglePlaces: (NSString *) googleType { } in delegate medhod.

Comment: - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    NSString *locationLabelOne=@"";
    NSString *locationLabelTwo=@"";
    locationLabelOne=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
   locationLabelTwo=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
coord.latitude = [locationLabelOne doubleValue];
    coord.longitude = [locationLabelTwo doubleValue];
    
     [self queryGooglePlaces:@"doctor"];}

Comment: Did like this but getting error :Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'

Comment: may be its bcoz i took radius as 300 and if >300 then its displaying error.How to get rid of this..?

Comment: did it.but many pinpoints are displayed above >300 radius region and the map is not static.It is automatically moving up and down

Comment: I think for every small change the method gets called, remove the [self  queryGooglePlaces:somestring]; from and the delegate and call it after the view loaded using Nstime or from some button actions if you have any.

Comment: [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
    target:self
    selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:NO];